# How to Create a Table based on example below, fields under Structure with multiple values in Access?

Tags: ms-access

Region:     Africa
Country:    South Africa
Project:
Developer:

**Structure**      **In Dataroom**      **Accurate**    **Fully Executed**
Bid Submission          Yes            Yes                 No
Bid Other           No                  No                 No
PPA         Yes             No             No
...

Comment: There's not enough info here for us to make sense of this question. Please expand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCTROW Count(db.[Accurate]) AS [Accurate].....
FROM db
Union ALL